# Conditionally rendering Font Awesome Icons

Tags: reactjs

I am currently mapping an array to produce several Font Awesome Icons. I have an OnClick method which I am using as a flag: I want to change the icon of only the clicked item. This is my implementation:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon id={i.key}  onClick={this.ToggleIcon}  icon={this.state.clicked ? faHeart : faCalendarAlt}/> 

ToggleIcon = (e) =>{
if((this.state.clicked)){
    this.setState({clicked: true})
  }


 else if!(this.state.clicked)){
   this.setState({clicked: false})
  }
}
```

However, this changes ALL of the icons instead of only the clicked one. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to track identifiers for your clicked objects in your state, instead of a simple boolean.

If you want only one icon to be 'clicked' at a time:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon id={i.key}  onClick={e => this.ToggleIcon(e, i.key)}  icon={this.state.clicked === i.key ? faHeart : faCalendarAlt}/> 

ToggleIcon = (e, key) =>{
    this.setState(prevState => {
        ...prevState,
        clicked: prevState.clicked === key ? null : key
    });
}
```

If you want to track clicked state for multiple icons:

```
import * as R from 'ramda';

...

// Init state with empty array
state = {
    clicked: [],
    // ...other state in this component
}

...

<FontAwesomeIcon id={i.key}  onClick={e => this.ToggleIcon(e, i.key)}  icon={R.includes(i.key, this.state.clicked) ? faHeart : faCalendarAlt}/> 

ToggleIcon = (e, key) =>{
    this.setState(prevState => {
        if (!R.includes(key, prevState.clicked)) {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                clicked: R.append(key, prevState.clicked)
            };
        }
        return {
            ...prevState,
            clicked: R.without(key, prevState.clicked)
        };
    });
}
```

I'm using `ramda` here, but you can use your preferred method of manipulating arrays without mutation.  This also assumes that `i.key` is a unique identifier for each icon.

For the second case, another approach would be to instead wrap each icon in a small component which handles its own state (and would look very similar to what you already have), which is a generally encouraged practice for performance reasons.  Whether it's the best approach will depend on the purpose of these icons and the purpose of their 'clicked' state, however.

Comment: How can ramda access i.key in the conditionally rendering?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  `ramda` is just used for manipulating arrays, in this example for adding/removing/searching.  `i.key` is available in the render scope according to your original code, and is provided to `ToggleIcon` through its second argument.  Each icon will be provided with a function that calls `ToggleIcon` with that icon's `key`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you rendering all those icons on the same component? If so, that's your problem. You're updating a state for the whole component, therefore the state value is equal everywhere, throughout it. So what's the solution? Right, it's to assign different `clicked` state key/value to each icon.

Array:

```
class Icons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      icons: []
    }
  }

  toggleIcon(index, event) {
    const iconState = this.state.icons[index] || {}
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      icons: [
        ...this.state.icons.slice(0, index),
        {
          ..._currentValue,
          clicked: !iconState.clicked
        },
        ...this.state.icons.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { ICONS.map((item, index) => {
          const iconState = this.state.icons[index] || {}
          return (
            <FontAwesomeIcon id={index}  onClick={this.toggleIcon.bind(this, index)}  icon={iconState.clicked ? faHeart : faCalendarAlt} /> 
          )
        }) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Object:

```
class Icons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      icons: {
        a: { clicked: false },
        b: { clicked: false }
      }
    }
  }

  toggleIcon(key, event) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      icons: {
        ...this.state.icons,
        [key]: {
          ...this.state.icons[key],
          clicked: !this.state.icons[key].clicked
        }
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FontAwesomeIcon id={'a'}  onClick={this.toggleIcon.bind(this, 'a')}  icon={this.state.icons.a.clicked ? faHeart : faCalendarAlt} /> 
        <FontAwesomeIcon id={'b'}  onClick={this.toggleIcon.bind(this, 'b')}  icon={this.state.icons.b.clicked ? 'icon 1' : 'icon 2' } /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

learn more:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: But I´m mapping the elements from an array, so I don´t know how many there will be.

Comment: @ReactDoubter In that case, the best approach would be to convert the `icons`  type to `array`. I've updated an answer with example, have a look.